# If two sample means of $X$ differ significantly and $X$ predicts $Y$, can it be inferred that the samples differ in their $Y$?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, inference

In the following model:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon $

$X$ is found to be significantly related to $Y$.

Now, I observe $X$ within two groups. I compare the two means and find that the $X$ values significantly differ between the two groups, on average.

Can I conclude that $Y$ is significantly different between the two groups?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "observe $X$ within two groups?" It is crucial to know whether these observations are part of the dataset used to fit the model or whether they are independent observations.

Comment: Thats a smart remark. They are used to fit the overall model. The sample used to estimate the model consists (exclusively) of the two abovementioned group samples.

Comment: You can't conclude much from this information, but why bother?  Couldn't you just directly test the two sets of $Y$ values corresponding to the two groups?  What is preventing that?

Comment: In general, you are right. I was just interested in wether one could draw such a conclusion or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Slightly simplified, you are saying that you do know that $cor(X, Y) \neq 0$, and that $cor(X, G) \neq 0$, where $G$ is the group indicator.

But correlation (or, more generally, statistical dependence) is not "transitive", so $cor(X, G) \neq 0$ does not follow.

The simplest counterexample is the causal graph $Y \rightarrow X \leftarrow G$. In this graph, $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, as well as $X$ and $G$, but $Y$ and $G$ are independent.